# What exactly does the "structures in a row" end game bonus mean?

Tags: scythe

The rulebook says the following:

> Number of your structures in a row (any continuous straight line is fine; only count the longest row of structures you have; rivers do not break continuity).

The last bit is obvious: rivers don't matter.  The "straight line" part is in parenthesis, so I assume that it isn't as important as the "in a row", so what does that mean?

Is it any continuous grouping, or is the straight line part more important than I assume, and the structures need to be along one of the hex rows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parenthesis disambiguates the phrase before it. "In a row" has its natural meaning, which is further clarified to be "any conti**n**uous straight line" (of hexes). A conti**g**uous grouping is not the same thing.